# Deployment failure: bad value for restricted picklist field

Tags: deployment, dml

I am facing a weird issue during production deployment.

I have **created a picklist field** (which is not exist in Production) `Lead_Assignment_Status__c` which is by-default restricted and values are `New` and `Assigned`. This picklist is not mandatory field.

[image: Lead Assignment Status]

In the `testSetup` method, created lead records as follows and updated `Lead_Assignment_Status__c = 'Assigned'`:

```
Lead objLead = new Lead();
        objLead.RecordTypeId = 'xxxx';
        objLead.Company = 'Test';
        objLead.FirstName = 'f1';
        objLead.LastName = 'l1';
        objLead.Lead_Stage__c = 'New';
        objLead.Status ='New';
        objLead.LeadSource ='External Referral';
        objLead.Email ='test@gmail.com';
        objLead.IsConverted = false;
        objLead.OwnerId = UserId; 
insert objLead;

//updates Lead with Assigned Status
       objLead.Lead_Assignment_Status__c = 'Assigned'; 
       update objLead;
```

During deployment this code snippet is failing with this error at this line `update objLead;`:

> System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 00Q16000018n8DREAY; first error: INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST, bad value for restricted picklist field: Assigned: [Lead_Assignment_Status__c]

When I run this test class at our development environment it is running without any errors.

My question is why this is failing during deployment.

Comment: Do the picklist values exist in production already?

Comment: no, its a new field

Comment: Try creating that field in Production and setting the picklist values before deploying and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: best information I've been able to find is a link to a blog: http://opfocus.com/bad-value-restricted-picklist-field-deployment-error/ . I didn't find anything specific in the Winter '17 release notes (and restricted picklists went GA in summer '16). Perhaps it's worth calling into Salesforce support.

Comment: you are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created this field in production prior to deploying test classes and it has been successfully deployed.

Thanks to [sfdcJameson](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/7505/sfdcjameson)

Answer (score 2):

If your Lead object employs **Record Types**, the most likely culprit for this error is that you have not included relevant **Record Type(s)** in your deployment.

The error `bad value for restricted picklist field` is encountered when a picklist option isn't available for that field under the specific **Record Type** of an inserted Lead record (perhaps the *default* Record Type, in your case).

Including the relevant Record Type in your deployment will bring over the picklist options for all picklist fields as they've been configured for that Record Type in your sandbox, and in most cases will resolve the error without having to create the field manually in Production beforehand.